# Where are files stored?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

I just needed a old file i deleted a few days back and I googled and got pandora recovery tool.
I was wondering how I can recover an item after deleting it from recycle bin.
After i delete a file how can it be restored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delete operation only doesn't remove the files from hard disk but those files are still there until some other file replaces/overwrites the previous file.

Comment: what if i sell my computer to someone else with so many sensitive data on hard disk ?

Comment: u should always clean/format your hard disk before selling.Hard disks once formatted no data can be retrived

Comment: i mean i use some data then delete it and my younger brother comes and restore it....that obviously i don't want ???

Answer (score 1):

A common misconception is that the data is actually removed from the hard drive (erased) when you delete a file. Any time that a file is deleted on a hard drive, it is not erased. Instead, the tiny bit of information that points to the location of the file on the hard drive is erased. This pointer, along with other pointers for every folder and file on the hard drive, is saved in a section near the beginning of the hard drive and is used by the operating system to compile the directory tree structure. By erasing the pointer file, the actual file becomes invisible to the operating system. Eventually, the hard drive will write new data over the area where the old file is located.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many open source software to undelete a file from

1. MiniTool Power Data Recovery (Free Edition)- http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/download.html
   You can recover upto 1 GB
2. Recuva - http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download